# Notes.app versioning

Tags: notes.app

I wanted to duplicate a note and remove some of the texts. But I forgot to duplicate the note. So I did remove most of my writings accidentally. Closed to app and when I went back on it I saw the disaster my work have been lost.

Is there a place where we can go back in time and choosing a note from versioning like on Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Time Machine? If yes, open Finder, go to `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/` and open Time Machine eg. from the icon in the top right. This should show you past versions of the files there. Close the notes app completely and try restoring files.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud only keeps backups of files in iCloud Drive, contacts, calendars, reminders and bookmarks.

If you have another device available which synchronises to the same iCloud account and may not have synchronised yet, turn Airplane Mode on from Control Center before unlocking the device and see if the content of the note is still there.